# How to get the Sub total at each row of the group using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I got a special requirement to show the Sub total at individual row of the group. I tried to rundown each row and using for-each-group function I grouped at Supplier Invoice number. But the results are showing just individual row value instead of subtotal amount. Can you guys show some lite here on how we can achieve this kind of requirement?

Sample Records:

```
    <Report_Data>
        <Report_Entry>
            <Supplier_Invoice_Number>SINV-01</Supplier_Invoice_Number>
            <Supplier_Invoice_Line>1</Supplier_Invoice_Line>
            <Memo>SC0590</Memo>
            <Amount>10</Amount>
        </Report_Entry>
        <Report_Entry>
            <Supplier_Invoice_Number>SINV-01</Supplier_Invoice_Number>
            <Supplier_Invoice_Line>2</Supplier_Invoice_Line>
            <Memo>SC0590</Memo>
            <Amount>-100</Amount>
        </Report_Entry>
        <Report_Entry>
            <Supplier_Invoice_Number>SINV-02</Supplier_Invoice_Number>
            <Supplier_Invoice_Line>1</Supplier_Invoice_Line>
            <Memo>SC0590</Memo>
            <Amount>10</Amount>
        </Report_Entry>
        <Report_Entry>
            <Supplier_Invoice_Number>SINV-02</Supplier_Invoice_Number>
            <Supplier_Invoice_Line>2</Supplier_Invoice_Line>
            <Memo>SC0590</Memo>
            <Amount>10</Amount>
        </Report_Entry>
    </Report_Data>
```

Expected Output:

```
    <Report_Data>
        <Report_Entry>
            <Supplier_Invoice_Number>SINV-01</Supplier_Invoice_Number>
            <Supplier_Invoice_Line>1</Supplier_Invoice_Line>
            <Memo>SC0590</Memo>
            <Amount>10</Amount>
            <SubTotal>-90</SubTotal>
        </Report_Entry>
        <Report_Entry>
            <Supplier_Invoice_Number>SINV-01</Supplier_Invoice_Number>
            <Supplier_Invoice_Line>2</Supplier_Invoice_Line>
            <Memo>SC0590</Memo>
            <Amount>-100</Amount>
            <SubTotal>-90</SubTotal>
        </Report_Entry>
        <Report_Entry>
            <Supplier_Invoice_Number>SINV-02</Supplier_Invoice_Number>
            <Supplier_Invoice_Line>1</Supplier_Invoice_Line>
            <Memo>SC0590</Memo>
            <Amount>10</Amount>
            <SubTotal>20</SubTotal>
        </Report_Entry>
        <Report_Entry>
            <Supplier_Invoice_Number>SINV-02</Supplier_Invoice_Number>
            <Supplier_Invoice_Line>2</Supplier_Invoice_Line>
            <Memo>SC0590</Memo>
            <Amount>10</Amount>
            <SubTotal>20</SubTotal>
        </Report_Entry>
    </Report_Data>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
        version="2.0">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="Report_Data">
            <Report_Data>
                <xsl:for-each select="Report_Entry">
                    <Report_Entry>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="Supplier_Invoice_Number"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="Supplier_Invoice_Line"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="Memo"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="Amount"/>
                        <SubTotal>
                            <xsl:for-each-group select="." group-by="Supplier_Invoice_Number">
                            <xsl:value-of select="sum(Amount)"/>
                            </xsl:for-each-group>
                        </SubTotal>
                    </Report_Entry>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Report_Data>
            
        </xsl:template>
        
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `select="."` will only ever select one item. It doesn't make sense to group a single item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will produce the output you expect:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Report_Data">
    <Report_Data>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Report_Entry" group-by="Supplier_Invoice_Number">
            <xsl:variable name="subtotal" select="sum(current-group()/Amount)" />
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <Report_Entry>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                    <SubTotal>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$subtotal"/>
                    </SubTotal>
                </Report_Entry>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Report_Data>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much y.arazim. I just tested the results are coming as expected.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I just accepted your answer.